# Horizontal artifacts between geotiff edges using gdalbuildvrt and gdaltranslate

Tags: gdal, geotiff

I am trying to merge a number of geotiffs into one large geotiff with overviews, however the final merged geotiff shows a number of horizontal artifacts around the edges of the original merged geotiffs ([see here for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVL3O.png)).

I create the merged file using the following code:

```
'''Produce Combined VRT'''
string ='gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "0 0 0 0" -hidenodata -r bilinear %s -overwrite %s' %(tmp_vrt, GDal_merge_string)
os.system(string)

'''Convert VRT to Geotiff'''
string ='gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask 4 --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK YES -of GTiff %s %s' %(tmp_vrt,tmp_fname)
os.system(string)
```

I have a hunch that this might have to do with using gdal_translate on a vrt, as the erorrs occur on the edges of the original geotiffs, and in this case it might be related or similar to [the issue found in this post](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-vrt-warping-precision-issues-and-tile-offsets-td5387989.html).

This code is using VRTs to combine the geotiffs for speed purposes, but perhaps it might be better to just merge these with gdalwarp?

**Edit:** I have reduced the number of flags and left out the overviews in the code above, as suggested in the comment below by Benjamin. The error seems to be produced in the code above. I think the issue may lie in the masking process. I guess at some point in the process of stacking the bands, the inputs are distorted. Is it generally inadvisable to gdal_translate VRTs?

Comment: It would help to remove some of the unnecessary tags to make the problem simpler to troubleshoot (for example, look at the resulting image without tiling, compression, overviews, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Benjamin , I have edited the code above to reduce it to just the flags required to produce the image.